# Footnote citations (using biblatex) not compiling with TeXShop

Tags: biblatex

I'm currently compiling a large article with footnote citations. Using the `biblatex` package and compiling in MacTeX, my document allegedly compiles without errors, but the footnotes do not compile correctly on the pdf, the output simply pasting the bib ids:

[image]

However, copying and pasting the same exact code and bib file into Overleaf, some of the footnotes now compile:

[image]

I'm wondering why half of these now compile in Overleaf, and why none of them compile correctly using MacTeX, even when I am told the transcript is written without errors? Thank you very much in advance for any insights in how to proceed to correctly compile these Author-Year footnote citations.

Comment: It's hard to say why some citations don't show in the Overleaf example without seeing the code. My best guess would be faulty entries that are skipped. But then Biber should warn you about that and you should be able to see that in the log files. In your TeXShop attempt the fact that no citations show at all suggests you did not run Biber. You need to compile your document with LaTeX, Biber, laTeX. LaTeX (Overleaf does that automatically behind the scenes). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/ for an explanation and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with your editor.

Comment: If simply running LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX does not result in the desired output we would need to see a short example document (along with a few example `.bib` entries) that shows what you are doing so far (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Please check that your MWE is usable by testing it in a new, empty project on Overleaf or in a new, empty folder on your machine before submitting it.

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now there is not a lot of help we can offer except for the very general remarks I already made. I would say that this question can not really be answered in its current form and I will vote to close it as *unclear what you are asking* in due time if there are no new developments.

Comment: Hi @moewe, thanks for responding. I was able to succesfully compile the citations using pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex, as well as with the natbib package (using `\citealt*{}`).. your suggestion to create a MWEB led to me debugging chunk by chunk, which was also helpful. Thanks again for sharing your LaTex knowledge!

Comment: Do you think it would help other people if you wrote an answers that explains what you did and how you got things to work? Or do we just close this question as *unclear what you are askin*? Or do you want to delete it, since it is solved now?